# Disallow googlebot from accessing statistics url

Tags: html, robots.txt

I have my domain which i host a link shortener similar to bitly. When someone makes a short link they can add a ~s to the end of the url and get access to statistics for that url.

Example:

[https://example.com/123~s](https://example.com/123%7Es)

[https://example.com/abc~s](https://example.com/abc%7Es)

[https://example.com/123~s](https://example.com/123%7Es)

Without the ~s in the end it works just like any other url shortener. I wonder if i somehow deny all search engines from indexing any page where the url is ending with the extra ~s in robots.txt ?

https://example.com/123 should be allowed but not [https://example.com/123~s](https://example.com/123%7Es)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `robots.txt` supports wildcards:

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /*~s
```